# Add multiple Elements into every entry in Drop-Down Menu Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a drop-down menu which supports an image on the left side, then two labels on top of each other, these also need to be different sized, and then on the initial button to open the menu, a down arrow on the right side.

For reference purposes, I am trying to clone the Outlook drop-down option in the Info Frame
[image: This does not include the original option to press]

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: How do I make this is the issue, Normal drop-down menus don't support this apparently so I'm asking if there is a work around

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter menus don't support that. You will have to create your own dropdown window and then managing all of the bindings for making it appear and disappear.

Comment: How would I do that?